# Vertically align font awesome icons to bottom

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I think I must be missing something simple here. Is it possible to align the glyph content / glyph itself to the bottom of a parent element?

Given [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/y3fzyv4a/1/), how can I keep all the icons to the bottom, no matter the icon?

Here's an image to better illustrate what I want:

[image]

Obviously I can have a different `line-height` property per icon, but I'm wondering if there's a more generic approach to this issue. Or if font-awesome ships with some helper classes similar to the [fixed width approach](http://fontawesome.io/examples/#fixed-width) (by using `fa-fw`).

Comment: It's like v-align `x` to the bottom of `y`, cannot think of any other way other than line-height or playing with margins.

Answer (score 3):

I did some digging around in Font Awesome and it didn't look like there were any solutions to a fixed glyph height. What I would do is add the following CSS and position each glyph out manually.

Happy coding!

```
.icon-elem {
  position: relative;
}
.fa-user {
  top: 7px;
}
.fa-cloud-upload {
  top: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah, seems like there is no other way. Maybe they could add a helper class for this scenario. I assume it would have an `em` line-height calculated for each glyph

Comment: The problem with the `em line-height` is that the glphs themselves have extra padding on the top and bottom, embedded in the line height, so you would still have to approximate the `line-height` manually. Let me know if you find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just had to figure this out so adding a very late answer. In [Fontawesome 5](https://fontawesome.com/) icon height is more standard, but if you want to move icons around within their box you can use [power-transforms](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/power-transforms).

Example:
`<i class="fas fa-upload" data-fa-transform="down-4"></i>` would move the upload icon closer to the bottom.

Comment: what do you mean by this? `In Fontawesome 5 icon height is more standard`? do you mean this height issue is fixed? am using react font awesome and cant seem to see any update to this height insanity